# quiero que la fecha no me permita mas ingresos

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, date

Buen dia tengo una pregunta lo que quiero es mostrar un script el cual cuando la gente se registra tiene derecho a dos dias para editarlo pasando eso saldria el error y retornaria a la pagina pero ya investigue y no encontre la forma que a dos dias pueda salir el error o me cicla con el if o no me lo da
se supone que necesito sacar la fecha de hoy con la fecha que se registro ejemplo
se registra 14/04/2020 y el date seria hoy 17/04/2020 como ya pasaron mas de dos dias quiero que me salga ese error

variable que trae la fecha del dia de hoy local
$date = date('d');
query para sacar fecha de phpmyadmin

```
$fecha_regis="
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    perm 
  WHERE 
  fecha_regis  

  ";

    if($date > $fecha_regis){

        echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert(" no tienes Autorizado editar!");
        window.location.href="permisos.php";
        </script>';
          return;

      }else{

      }
$date =date('Y-m-d')  ;
$quer="
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    perm 
  WHERE 
  fecha_regis 


  ";
if( $quer >=$date  ){

echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert(" no tienes Autorizado editar!");
        window.location.href="permisos.php";
        </script>';
          return;


  }else {
      echo 'no quer es menor';
  }
```

Comment: A `$fecha_regis` le estás asignando un string con la consulta, no la fecha que buscas. Ajusta tu código, convierte el resultado a fecha y podrás operar con fechas (que es el mejor camino)

Comment: la variable le agrege con el nombre de la columna fecha ya que en phpmyadmin esta como date pero no se como convertirla

Comment: Una cosa es como están representados los datos en la BD, y otra es cómo los tiene PHP cuando los consulta. No es inmediata la conversión de lo que entrega el query, a un Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57209867/236345), podrías usar una función para obtener el intervalo en días y saber si es mayor a dos.

```
function interval2days($day, $interval) {
    $date = clone $day;
    $day2 = clone $interval;
    $start = $day2->getTimeStamp();
    $end = $date->getTimeStamp();
    return ($end-$start)/86400;
}
...
if( interval2days($date,$fecha_regis) > 2 ){
...
```

Comment: lo agrege tal cual pero me marco error

Comment: @RobertJosueMendoza No sé si lograste resolver el problema o no. Por si acaso, añadí un comentario a tu pregunta sobre la causa.

Comment: @RobertJosueMendoza entonces tu fragmento está incompleto. La función que sugiero usa dos fechas.

Comment: pero lo dejo con una o con dos

Comment: @RobertJosueMendoza Es tu elección. Obtener la fecha de hoy se puede hacer dentro de la función y podrías entregarle sólo la fecha resultado de la consulta, como objeto Date.

Comment: as ce cuenta lo tengo asi

Comment: $quer="
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    perm 
  WHERE 
  fecha_regis 
 

  ";

Comment: if( $quer =$date  ){

echo 'si qer es mayor';

 
  }else {
   echo 'no quer es menor';
  }
 

  
 
  
?>

Comment: $date =date('Y-m-d')  ;

Comment: @RobertJosueMendoza por favor, añade la info adicional a la pregunta y yo edito la respuesta. Si sigues, nos mandan a hacer un chat para revisar lo que comentas